# Java - when there is no need of writing to file - should I use input or output stream?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, outputstream

I'm getting from the client an inputStream and file Metadata, and saving it in my SQL table. This table also holds full file path and some unique uid.

I want to be able to pass a uid and get a "handler" to the file, but can't seem to understand if I need to return outputStream, InputStream or File?
Which one should be returned?

I want this handler for the client for the following reasons:

- The user will pass it to another function
- The user will decide to convert stream to a file and copy it to some local path

Also, When returning outputstram,is it enough to do the following:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(PATH_TO_MY_FILE))
return out;
```

Am I returning an empty stream? Does `out` contain all file data?

I thought maybe the best way will be to return file:

```
File f = new File(PATH_TO_MY_FILE);
return f;
```

Editing:
My metadata holds file name and file type. When I get InputStream I save in in my folder and set the path in the SQL table to be : `folerPath+"/"+filename + "."+ fileType`

When The user will run the following function : `get(fileUid)` I want to retrieve the full path (by using sql query) and return the file (hanlder)

Can you please advise?

Thanks

Comment: You said your file was in your database table, so what would `PATH_TO_MY_FILE` be?

Comment: Eh? You can't return a File unless there is a physical file on the disk. You can return an input stream or an output stream *depending on what the caller needs to do with it.* The problem barely arises.

Comment: I'm saving the file in my DB, but I don't want the user to get a file path string. I want him to get the file itself (and he will decide what to do with it)

Answer (score 1):

> The user will decide to convert stream to a file and copy it to some local path

This tells us that what you need to give *them* is an `InputStream` (or `Reader`), since they'll be *reading* from it.

*Your code* will be reading from your database or whatever, presumably via the `InputStream` you get back from [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream-int-) or similar. You might give that directly to the caller, or you may prefer to have your code in the middle, perhaps working through a memory buffer.

---

Re your comment below:

> I'm saving the file at some DB folder...

Databases don't have folders; *file systems* have folders. It sounds like the file **isn't** stored in your database table, just the path to it. If so, use `FileInputStream` with the path to get an `InputStream` for it, which you can return to the caller.

Comment: Thanks T.J, so should I return : new InputStream(FILE_PATH) and that is it? Will this inputStream contain all data? How can I convert it later to a file?

Comment: Again, what path would that be? You said the data was in a database. *"How can I convert it later to a file?"* You read it, and if you need to write a file, you write the data to a file.

Comment: Yes, I'm saving the file at some DB folder and adding an sql entry will full file path. When the users asks for the file, I dont want to return the path, I want the file itself (file/inputstream)

Comment: @user1386966: *"I'm saving the file at some DB folder..."* Databases don't have folders; *file systems* have folders. It sounds like the file **isn't** stored in your database table, just the path to it. If so, use `FileInputStream` with the path to get an `InputStream` for it.

Comment: yes you are corrent, sorry, I'm saving in DB only file path, and the file itselfd is in some folder in my computer